# Contractibility of the category of cosimplicial resolutions

Tags: at.algebraic-topology, ct.category-theory, homotopy-theory, simplicial-stuff, model-categories

Let $\gamma : \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{M}$ be a functor and define a cosimplicial resoultion of $\gamma$ as a functor $\Gamma: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$ such that

- $\Gamma C$ is Reedy cofibrant for every $C \in \mathcal{C}$
- for every $C$ there is a natural weak equivalence $w(C):\Gamma C \xrightarrow{\sim} c^* \gamma C $

We can define a category $\mathcal{R}=\text{coRes}(\gamma)$ where the morphisms are natural transformations $\eta:\Gamma_1 \to \Gamma_2$ such that for all $C$ the obvious triangles commute i.e. we have $w_2(C) \circ \eta_C = w_1(C)$ for all $C.$

> I would like to understand why this category, as is well known, is
> contractible.

Since I do not understand anything of the proof I found in the text I consulted, I am trying to prove it by myself in the following way:

- A resolution exists because for every $C,$ we can find a cofibrant object $X_C$ in $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$ and a weak equivalence $X_C \xrightarrow{\sim} c^*\gamma C$ and this defines a functor $X(C)=X_C$ by functorial factorization.
- For every $\Gamma \in \mathcal{R},$ by functorial factoriazion there is a morphism $X \to \Gamma.$
- If I call weak equivalence in $\mathcal{R}$ a map $\eta$ such that $\eta_C$ is a weak equivalence in the Reedy model structure in $\mathcal{M}^{\Delta}$ for all $C,$ then given any map of resolutions $\eta:\Gamma_1 \to \Gamma_2,$ by commutativity of the triangle we have that $\eta$ is a weak equivalence under this defintion.
- Now, my naive intuition is that the contractibility of $\mathcal{R}$ should follow from the fact that if we formally invert all morphisms in $\mathcal{R}=\text{coRes}(\gamma)$, the resulting localization $\mathcal{R}[\mathcal{R}^{-1}]$ is a simply connected groupoid, hence contractible.
- I put on $\mathcal{R}$ the equivalence relation given by identifying all parallel morphisms, which is a congruence. In this way, all morphisms become invertible in the quotient so that I can call $\mathcal{R}/{\sim}=\mathcal{R}[\mathcal{R}^{-1}]$ and I have the quotient functor $q:\mathcal{R}\to \mathcal{R}[\mathcal{R}^{-1}].$
- For every $\Gamma,$ the arrow category $\Gamma \downarrow q$ is contractible having initial object, so I conclude by Quillen's theorem A.

> Is this proof reasonable?

**Edit** The last bullet point is wrong because when I pass to the comma category I lose the initial object.

Also, apparently we cannot just pass to the quotient without using some extra propery of $\mathcal{R}$: if it were possible to apply the reasoning I wanted to make, it would imply that any category with an object $X$ such that $\text{Hom}(X,A) \neq \emptyset$ and $\text{Hom}(A,X) \neq \emptyset$ for all $A$ would become contractible. And I just found counterexamples to this fact in this other [question](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/348067/about-contractibility-of-certain-categories).

> I still wonder if by using some more property of $\mathcal{R}$, for example the fact that the maps I am inverting were all weak equivalences in some model structure, we can still deduce the contractibility of $\mathcal{R}$ from that of $\mathcal{R}[\mathcal{R}^{-1}]$ along the quotient functor in this case.

Comment: Isn't this much easier? In coRes($\gamma$), every object comes equipped with a weak equivalence to the terminal object. So it's contractible. Sure, if you like, you could point out that the homotopy category (of the Reedy model structure, say) is a groupoid, by the two out of three property for weak equivalences, but I think the statement is just obvious. Unless there's a subtlety I'm missing?

Comment: Why is the object terminal? I don’t see why the morphism is unique, maybe it’s me

Comment: @DavidWhite If by terminal object you mean the identity $c^*\gamma \to c^*\gamma$, then I think this does not belong to $\text{coRes}\gamma$ since $c^*\gamma C$ is not necessarily cofibrant. If instead you mean the object I call $X,$ then I don't see why the morphism should be unique. But it's possible I made a big deal out of something obvious?

Comment: @giuseppe A category $\mathcal{C}$ such that the 1-groupoid $\mathcal{C} [\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$ is simply connected may not be contractible. That would be like saying that any simply connected space is contractible.

Comment: @ZhenLin I am saying that the groupoid $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$ is contractible. Maybe I am using the wrong terminology but by simply connected groupoid I mean that parallel arrows are equal. The proof that the category $\mathcal{C}$ is contractible is in the two last bullets.

Comment: @ZhenLin Maybe by your comment you wanted to remark that for general $\mathcal{C}$ we can't always deduce contractibility of  $\mathcal{C}$ from that of $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$ ? But my point was that we could do that whenever there was an appropriate functor between the two as in the last two bullets.

Comment: There is nothing in your last two bullet points that uses special properties of $\mathcal{R}$, so it must be wrong.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don't see how "There is nothing in your last two bullet points that uses special properties..." is a valid mathematical reason to say that "it must be wrong". Many proofs can work in a more general context. And it used functorial factorization to show any two objects where connected through $X$. That said, I realized that my last bullet is not OK because when you pass to the comma category you don't have an initial object anymore.

Comment: It's called [proving too much](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proving_too_much). Your argument, as it stood, would have shown that any connected category whatsoever is contractible, which is obviously nonsense, as you realised. It seems you have also realised your other mistake, which is that you have not shown $\mathcal{R} / {\sim}$ is isomorphic to $\mathcal{R} [\mathcal{R}^{-1}]$ or, equivalently, that $\mathcal{R} [\mathcal{R}^{-1}]$ is contractible.

Comment: @ZhenLin Can you give me an "obvious" example of a non contractible category $\mathcal{C}$ with an object $X$ which is both weakly initial and weakly terminal and such that $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$ is a simply connected groupoid?

Comment: I don’t think there are any obvious examples, since the condition of having an object that is simultaneously weakly initial and weakly terminal makes analysis of the homotopy type complicated. But there exists a non-contractible simply connected one-object category.

Comment: @ZhenLin I don’t understand what definition of simply connected category you are using. Isn’t a simply connected one object category just a point? If any two parallel arrows are equal there is only the identity map.

Comment: For the purposes of this question, a simply connected category is one whose nerve is simply connected. Indeed, a simply connected one-object _groupoid_ must be a point, but this is not so for categories.

Comment: @ZhenLin Ok so your claim is that there exist a non contractible category with one object and some endomorphism which is not iso, and the nerve of this category is simply connected. But then when I was saying simply connected all this time I was using a different definition: which is that any two parallel arrows must be equal. But then under this definition any simply connected category would be a groupoid. So maybe my definition is only good for groupoids and equivalent to yours in that case

Comment: The category of resolutions is not simply connected in that strong sense, so it isn't the appropriate definition in this context.

Comment: @ZhenLin sure but I never claimed that. I always used that definition only for the groupoid $\mathcal{C}[\mathcal{C}^{-1}]$

Answer (score 6):

Since you have functorial factorisations you should exploit that to the hilt.

If $\mathcal{M}$ is a model category with functorial factorisations then the category $\mathbf{c}\mathcal{M}$ of cosimplicial objects in $\mathcal{M}$, with the Reedy model structure, is also a model category with functorial factorisations. There is an obvious fully faithful embedding $\mathcal{M} \to \mathbf{c} \mathcal{M}$, so we may as well just forget about cosimplicial objects and just prove the following claim:

> For every model category $\mathcal{M}$ with functorial factorisations and every diagram $F: \mathcal{C} \to \mathcal{M}$, the full subcategory $\mathcal{Q} (F)$ of the over-category $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{M}]_{/ F}$ spanned by the componentwise cofibrant replacements of $F$ is contractible.

Indeed, let $Q : \mathcal{M} \to \mathcal{M}$ be a functor and let $p : Q \Rightarrow \textrm{id}_\mathcal{M}$ be a natural transformation such that, for every object $M$ in $\mathcal{M}$, $Q M$ is a cofibrant object in $\mathcal{M}$ and $p_M : Q M \to M$ is a weak equivalence in $\mathcal{M}$. Such $Q$ and $p$ exist because $\mathcal{M}$ has functorial factorisations. Then, for every natural transformation $\alpha : F' \Rightarrow F$ and every object $C$ in $\mathcal{C}$, we have the following commutative square in $\mathcal{M}$:
$$\require{AMScd}
\begin{CD}
Q F' C @>{p_{F' C}}>> F' C \\
@V{Q \alpha_C}VV   @VV{\alpha_C}V \\
Q F C  @>>{p_{F C}}> F C
\end{CD}$$
This is all natural in $C$, so we actually have a commutative square in $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{M}]$, hence a zigzag $(Q F, p F) \leftarrow (Q F', \alpha \bullet p F') \rightarrow (F', \alpha)$ in the overcategory $[\mathcal{C}, \mathcal{M}]_{/ F}$. But $(Q F, p F)$ is a componentwise cofibrant replacement of $F$, and this is natural in $F'$, so we have a zigzag of natural transformations connecting the identity functor on $\mathcal{Q} (F)$ and a constant functor. Therefore $\mathcal{Q} (F)$ is contractible.

If you are geometrically inclined, you may think of the above proof as constructing a deformation retract of $\mathcal{Q} (F)$ to a point. Of course, any space with a deformation retract to a point is contractible. The gist of the argument is widely applicable and can be used in contexts where one does not have a model structure per se – this, I think, is the point of Part II of *Homotopy limit functors on model categories and homotopical categories*.

Comment: Thanks but I am not interested in another proof, there's a proof of this result on any book and they are all similar to this one. I wanted to see if my proof could work and I realized there is a point that does not work (thank you for making me think more about the last bullet). I never asked for a different proof so I'm sorry but I don't see how this is an answer to my question.

Comment: I'm surprised you say that you "don't understand anything of the proof", then – this is a much easier proof than what you proposed. It doesn't even rely on Quillen's Theorem A, which in my view is a non-trivial result concerning homotopy colimits.

Comment: OK. But how do you show that a zig-zag of natural transformations connecting the identity functor and a constant functor is a sufficient condition for contractibility? It seems that is where all the meat of the proof is.

Comment: I see the analogy in the sense that if we define a homotopy between functors as a zig-zag of natural transformations, then clearly by your proof we retract $Q(F)$ to a point by deformation. But why is this the right notion of homotopy which agrees with the definition of contractibility that uses the nerve?

Comment: Apply the nerve functor. The natural transformations literally become simplicial homotopies. If you prefer to work with actual topological spaces then apply the geometric realisation functor as well.

Comment: Sorry if I come back on this but I was looking at the proof with more care and I realized I don't actually understand. I don't see how you built the zig-zag of natural transformations from the identity to the constant functor. For starters, who would be the constant functor? On which object it is constant?

Comment: Constant on $Q F$.

Comment: In your diagram, you are just restating the fact that what you call $p$ is a natural transformation from $Q$ to the identity on $\mathcal{M}.$ What I do not understand is how does this say that there is "a zigzag of natural transformations connecting the identity functor on $\mathcal{Q} (F)$ and a constant functor". What constant functor?

Comment: And where is the zig-zag?

Comment: I thought what you were trying to do was to connect any other cofibrant replacement to $QF$ through $F.$ But $F$ lies outside the category, so it can't be what you were doing.

Comment: Or maybe you are taking $F' $ already a cofibrant replacement?

Comment: The intermediate is $Q F'$. $F'$ is cofibrant for the purposes of this question but it doesn’t really matter.

Comment: As I understand it, what you have done is say that for any resolution $\Gamma,$ you have a wk $\Gamma \to X,$ (what I called $X$ in my question) and you claim that this is natural w.r.t. maps $\Gamma_1 \to \Gamma_2,$ which I don't see how.

Comment: Sorry I didnt see your reply. So you are taking a cofibrant replacement of an object which is already cofibrant? $F'$ must be cofibrant otherwise it's not even in the category we want to prove is contractible, this is what I was saying.

Comment: Do you agree or I’m still not understanding ?

Comment: Yes, you take a functorial cofibrant replacement of a cofibrant replacement.

Comment: I guess I still have a problem. What you are doing is take the image of the functor $Q$ and take the slice over $F$ and show is contractible. I’m not sure this is the category of resolutions. Because not all maps of resolutions come from functorial factorization. The fact that lets you say that $p$ is a natural transformation is that all maps in your category come from functorial factorization; but this is not the case in the category of resolutions, where there are more maps.

Comment: Probably to complete your proof one needs to show that the category you built is a deformation retract of the category of resolutions.

Comment: This is more or less what is done in Hirschhorn theorem 14.5.4

Comment: The smallest category for which this argument works is indeed the image of the functor $Q$ in the slice category over $F$. But it also works for any other subcategory of the slice over $F$ that contains the image of $Q$.